# Pythonic way to Call a function with set of arguments until it return any thing but None

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know to use for loop and call my function till I get not None as return value, But I am looking for some python built in which can help here.

e.g. - `iter(myfunc(), None)` It will call `myfunc()` until it return `None`

I am looking to code exactly opposite to this e.g. - `iter(myfunc(), not None), Call myfunc()` until it returns any thing but `None`

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `from itertools import dropwhile, repeat, starmap; next(dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, starmap(my_func, repeat(()))))`

Comment: What is my_func() doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it apply regular expression on argument and return matched object

Comment: Yes that string would be lines from a file and keep calling this until I get matched object

Comment: So what you really want is the first not-None value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just three lines:

```
x = None
while x is None:
    x = f()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not look for a builtin for everything. In my opinion even the usual two-argument form of `iter` is not worth using because it's not a well known feature, and that makes it harder for most people to read. Just keep it simple and straightforward. An extra line or two will not hurt.

```
while True:
    x = myfunc()
    if x is not None:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready builtin, but it is easy enough to build a generator function:

```
def iter_while_none(f):
    while True:
        value = f()
        if value is not None:
            return
        yield value
```

although the value yielded is not that interesting; it is, after all, `None` each time.

Comment: I think OP did not make it very clear, but they want to know what that non-None value is. This solution drops that value.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit of an exercise in the power of Python. I just get frustrated that `iter`s 2-arity form doesn't take a function for its second parameter.

But it does, if you're crazy enough. See, you can redefine equality on an object, like so:

```
class Something:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.lastother = other
        return other is not None

sentinel = Something()
myiter = iter(myfunc, sentinel)
for nope in myiter:
    pass
match = sentinel.lastother
```

There. Enjoy. Python's pretty amazing that you can subvert the definition of equality this way. Have fun storming the castle!

Comment: Are you kidding? Upvote this answer for its amusement and educational factors, but please don't accept it! Accepting it means unthinking script kiddies will copypaste it and it'll end up on some production system. I don't want to be responsible for that! Accept Vpfb's answer instead, please!

Comment: I liked this answer most, so I accepted it, I would respect your wish

Comment: @AlokThakur I appreciate that, but the code I wrote is more pedagogical than right. You really should consider Vpfb's answer.